# bash decrypt file stored in MySQL

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl

I'm storing a xls file in a MySQL table and before saving I've encrypted it.

The file is encrypted using PHP:

```
$key='------------'; // not the real key or iv.
$iv = "*********";
$file = file_get_contents('original.xls');
$file = openssl_encrypt($file, "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
```

and then inserted into an existing MySQL table.

In PHP I can download this using a select statement and then decrypt and save it as follows using the same key & iv:

```
$file = openssl_decrypt($file, "AES-256-CBC", $key, 0, $iv);
file_put_contents('downloaded.xls', $file);
```

I'm now trying to do the same via a bash script.

The encrypted data is read from MySQL using:

```
xls=$(mysql -N -u root --password=1234 test -e "SELECT foo FROM bar where id = '1'")
```

I'm then trying to decrypt and save it using:

```
key='------------'
iv = "*********"
ivHex=$(printf "%s" "$iv" | hexdump -ve '/1 "%x"')
keyHex=$(printf "%s" "$key" | hexdump -ve '/1 "%x"')
file=$(echo -n $xls| openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -A -K $keyHex -iv $ivHex)
    
echo $file > bash.xls
```

Unfortunately this results in the error "**command substitution: ignored null byte in input**", the file is saved but it is smaller than the original file and corrupt.

If I do this using plain text in the MySQL database, then I can download and decrypt it fine using php or bash.

Can anyone advise what is causing this and how I can resolve it ?

thanks

I should have said I have tried using `tr -d '\0'` but that resulted in the same error message.

Comment: @Amadan that may help, but to honest I'm not sure how to implement it. Could you offer some advise ? Thanks

Comment: The issue is that bash does not allow storing `\0` in a variable (or a command argument either, for that matter). And you can't simply ignore `\0`, as it would change the encrypted file. So you will want to do this without an intermediary variables `$file` and `$xls`, which could potentially contain it: `mysql .... | openssl .... > bash.xls`

Comment: @Amadan - that makes sense. I've tested this and it is working. Could you create this as an answer for me to accept. Thanks